# Magento - Get the Skin URL

Tags: magento, skin

I'd like to call the URL for my Magento store's skin for the purpose of loading an image. I've read that you can use `<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/ sampleimage.gif', array('_secure'=>true)) ?>`, but I get a "Call to undefined method" by using that. I've tried looking for a `Mage::getModel` version of this method, but I can't find it.

I did find Alan Storm's article, which got me most of the way there: http://alanstorm.com/magento_base_directories. Alan says I can use `Mage::getBaseDir(‘skin’)`, and I've found `Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getPackageName()`. I can't find a way to get the last part of the skin directory. If my current skin was `/skin/frontend/base/default/` I've so far got it to `/skin/frontend/base/`, I just need to be able to get Magento to give me the last, `/default/`, part of the directory.

I'm hoping that I'm barking up the wrong tree here and that there's a nice Mage::getModel method that I can call, like the `$this->getSkinUrl`. Can you help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are perfectly right in your assomption and the model is `Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package`

So this do the trick :

```
echo Mage::getModel('core/design_package')->getSkinUrl();
```

I did found that this way :
I know the function I (or in this case you) are looking for, so I just try to get the file where it is :

```
grep -Rni 'function getSkinUrl' .
./app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php:482:    public function getSkinUrl($file = null, array $params = array())
```

Great, now I just have to translate the file to its handle so `Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package` becomes `core/design_package`

As discovered during some core lookup in the comments, another way to do it would be simply to use:

```
Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl()
```

Comment: Super, thank you. I've just popped the hood on that PHP file, I'll have a little dig through it. In the meantime, that's spot on and works exactly the way I want it to.

Comment: @user2036972 Btw where are you trying to do that ? Maybe you just get this error because you forget to extend or extended the wrong class.

Comment: i'm glad you asked where and not why! I'm trying to do it in /app/design/frontend/xxxx/xxxx/template/page/1column.phtml and I expect this means I could use a different, easier, method but your code will work anywhere.

Comment: Nope, I was just wondering... Strange because the code says `1column.phtml` is of type `Mage_Page_Block_Html` which, in the end extends `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` with the function `getSkinUrl` as define `return Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl($file, $params);` (hey another way to get what you want, just `Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl()` )... So using `$this` _should_ work.

Comment: That last comment clicked a couple of things together in my head. I'm going to have to trace a few things back through the core now. Makes sense, and the new code you provided also works, I'll have a play with it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Mage::getSkinUrl('images/imagename.gif', array('_secure'=>true));

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage::getSkinUrl()

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN);

Comment: that just gets me to /skin/ - I'd got that far. I'm looking for /skin/frontend/base/default/.